# crm advanced developer tools in conjunction with WCF not working

Tags: wcf, ado.net, dynamics-crm

I created a simple wcf service that retrieves data from crm 4.0 using the advanced developer tools. I queried the data successfully using linq. The classes were generated using crmsvcutil. However, when I converted this to a wcf service as below it keeps crashing.

```
namespace CRMDataRetrieval
 {    
 [ServiceContract]
public interface ICRMData
{
    [OperationContract]
    string getValue();

}

public class CRMDataService : ICRMData
{
    public string getValue()
    {
        DataContext context = new DataContext("entities");  //entities is name of    classes that were generated by crmsvcutil

        string name = null;
        var query = from n in context.contacts
                    where n.acctNum == "01218515"
                    select n.nickname;
        foreach (var result in query)
            name = result;
        return name;
    }
```

In the WCF Service Host, the service is stopped but it also shows Entities.CmsDataService as being stopped as well. When i click on this, the additional Information says that The service(Entities.CmsDataService) cannot be started. This service has no endpoint defined. Please add at least one endpoint for the service in config file and try again.

As things stand my app.config looks like below. **So how and where would I add the endpoints in the config file for the autogenerated classes so that they work nicely with WCF**? or would I need to make any other changes? **Please be detailed in your explanation**. As usual, thanking you in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="entities" connectionString="Authentication Type=ad; Server=http://****; User ID=*\*******; Password=*******"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="CRMDataRetrieval.CRMDataService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7432/account"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint name="wsHttpBinding_ICRMData" address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CRMDataRetrieval.ICRMData"/>


        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>

      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: Definetely your endpoind configurations are correct. I'm little bit confused with 'Entities.CmsDataService'. Absolutely unclear where this name comes from. There should be something like 'CRMDataRetrieval.CRMDataService'.<br> And I do not like class name DataContext. It should be generated class, but there are possible naming conflicts with other .Net namespaces, like System.Data.Linq

Comment: Entities is the folder that contains all the classes generated by crmsvcutil which I include in my project with the using statement. CmsDataServices happens to be one of those auto-generated classes. How do you suggest I proceed without DataConext? I'm happy to give it a try. Can you provide details? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Quick note, If there is an auto generated class DataContext, how do I go about including and using it? Please provide steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [crmsvcutil parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681563.aspx). There are /dataContextPrefix and /dataContextClassName. Use these parameters to set proper name for generated data context. Use the generated context as it described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681574.aspx)

```
CrmConnection crmc = CrmConnection.Parse("Authentication Type=Passport; Server=https://" + org + ".crm.dynamics.com/" + org + "; User ID=myuser; Password=mypassword; Device ID=mydeviceid; Device Password=mydevicepassword");
var yourDataContext = new GeneratedDataContext(crmc);
```

Unfortunately I don't have CRM 4.0 installed. But I can provide code for CRM 2011:

```
namespace CRMDataRetrieval
{
    public class CRMDataService : ICRMData
    {
        public string getValue()
        {
            var connection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com; Username=OpenId; Password=; DeviceID=####; DevicePassword=####");
            var service = new OrganizationService(connection);
            MyServiceContext context = new MyServiceContext(service);

            string name = null;
            var query = from n in context.ContactSet
                        where n.ContactId == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                        select n.FullName;
            foreach (var result in query)
                name = result;

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

I used endpoint configuration you provided.

To generate classes I used

```
crmsvcutil.exe /url:https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:GeneratedCode.cs /n:MyCrmNamespace /u:"OpenId" /p:"####" /serviceContextName:MyServiceContext /di:#### /dp:####
```

Comment: this worked for me. The only change I made was to delete the cmsdatacontextclass which was auto-genereated and had no use for and specify the servicecontext when using crmsvcutil while abandoning the datacontext class I created above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you bring up an hello world endpoint and consume it? Once you have that, you can use the working code you've already written. (unless crmsvcutil generate some classes that are designed for hosting a wcf endpoint I am not aware of?)

I agree with paramosh -- 'Entities.CmsDataService' isn't the name of the service I would expect given your example. I would have expected 'CRMDataRetrieval.CRMDataService'